# SharePoint 2013 - User Profile Service not updating

Tags: user-profile-service, active-directory-import

I have SP2013 farm that is configured to sync with three AD domains:

EU
AP
US

We've had to amend the import of these three domains, so that we limit the OU's we're synching with. It used to be that I imported the Account OU and everything below it. Now, we're being a bit more picky.

So far, I've had to remove the existing connection, and create a new one, limited to the OU's that I want to import. For some reason, amending the original has no effect - it reverts back to what it was before the change.

My new connections are not updating the profiles that are store - I was expecting the number of profiles to drop from 6'510 to around 500 with the changes I've made.

I have performed an incremental and full sync a number of times, as well as start/stop the user profile service.

Nothing is changing however.

Is there a step I'm missing?

We're running build 15.0.4571.1502 (Fixed SP1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is normal.

You have My Site Cleanup Job timer job for that situation.
You have to wait for cleanup.

http://platinumdogs.me/2012/10/18/sharepoint-demystifying-user-profile-deletion-mysite-removal/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/06/25/top-recommendations-for-managing-the-my-site-cleanup-timer-job.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links, however this isn't related to the MySites - this is about the number of users being syncronised. Running the MySite cleanup job didn't make any changes.

Comment: User profiles are deleted after several cleanup jobs not immediately.

Comment: Thanks eVT - I seem some of the user profile jobs are set to be run daily, so I may need to wait 24 hours. I just assumed that an incremental or full would clean it up right away.